# How to write JUnit tests for menus?

Tags: android, menu

I'd like to test that my activity has the correct number of menu items. How do I get a reference to the menu items from an ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 ?

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this:

```
public class MyTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyActivity> {

    // Snip boilerplate and setUp() 
    private static final int CORRECT_NUMBER = 5;

    public void testMenu() {
        MenuClass menu = (MenuClass) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_menu);

        assert(CORRECT_NUMBER, menu.getAdapter().getCount());
    }
}
```